# Android resources not found in Flutter project

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I'm trying to follow the guideline to add an image into the splash screen.
The project is built and runs as expected, but the resource in `@mipmap/ic_launcher` is red, and Android studio reports `can not resolve symbols`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Open your project like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53120219/6618622), does it still show the error?

Comment: Thank you. So it's not a good idea to open one single Android studio instance to work with Flutter. Instead, I should open an Android studio instance for the Android part, an XCode instance for the iOS part and at the end a whatever IDE for the dart/flutter part. Are you agree with this?

Comment: I agree with you. But the latest update of Flutter plugin for AS seems to provide some relief. Anyways did the link work for you?

Comment: Yes, thanks. It seems to work. ;)

Answer (score 6):

When your Flutter project is open in Android Studio, it doesn't seem to respect all of the Android conventions in the `android` subfolder of the Flutter project.

As was noted in the comment link, though, you can go to **File > Open** and open the `android` folder. This will recognize it as an Android project and the resource errors should be gone.

That said, you don't need to open it as an Android project. You can just ignore the "errors" and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also go to

> Tools > Flutter > Open Android module in Android Studio

[image]